# Struts2 data tranfer from Jsp to Action using Complex Objects

Tags: struts2, model-driven

how to use Model-driven or Object-backed approaches to map Complex Object with depth more than one. for example, I have action class with property User object and USer has a address object as its property. Address has street name as property. like .. User.address.streetName

In JSP, using s:textfield or other tags how can I represent street name.?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What is the problem with this?

```
<s:property value="user.address.streetName" />
```

In the traditional setting, this will call `yourAction.getUser().getAddress().getStreetName()`

And in the other way, eg. when submiting a form (jsp to Action), that would translate to 
`yourAction.getUser().getAddress().setStreetName(param)`
For this to work, you just must be sure that `getUser()` and `getAddress()` do not return null (or at least that Struts can create -with empty constructor- and set that objects, IIRC).

Comment: Thank you. I am testing that. Is it also possible to have Objects generalized. I mean can we use Base class and Subclass concept with the JSP to Action data mapping